# How do I create a function with a pandas dataframe that uses two column headers as arguments to then print a preexisting 3rd column value?

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this. 3 columns.  All I want to do is write a FUNCTION that, when the first two columns are inputs, the corresponding third column (GHG intensity) is the output. I want to be able to input any property name and year and achieve the corresponding GHG intensity value. Please help!

```
                               Property Name  Data Year  
467                             GALLERY 37       2018   
477                        Navy Pier, Inc.       2016   
1057                            GALLERY 37       2015   
1491                       Navy Pier, Inc.       2015   
1576                            GALLERY 37       2016   
2469                   The Chicago Theatre       2016   
3581                       Navy Pier, Inc.       2014   
4060                        Ida Noyes Hall       2015   
4231               Chicago Cultural Center       2015   
4501                            GALLERY 37       2017   
5303                         Harpo Studios       2015   
5450                   The Chicago Theatre       2015   
5556               Chicago Cultural Center       2016   
6275   MARTIN LUTHER KING COMMUNITY CENTER       2015   
6409   MARTIN LUTHER KING COMMUNITY CENTER       2018   
6665                        Ida Noyes Hall       2017   
7621                        Ida Noyes Hall       2018   
7668   MARTIN LUTHER KING COMMUNITY CENTER       2017   
7792                   The Chicago Theatre       2018   
7819                        Ida Noyes Hall       2016   
8664   MARTIN LUTHER KING COMMUNITY CENTER       2016   
8701                   The Chicago Theatre       2017   
9575               Chicago Cultural Center       2017   
10066              Chicago Cultural Center       2018   

       GHG Intensity (kg CO2e/sq ft)  
467                             7.50  
477                            22.50  
1057                            8.30  
1491                           23.30  
1576                            7.40  
2469                            4.50  
3581                           17.68  
4060                           11.20  
4231                           13.70  
4501                            7.90  
5303                           18.70  
5450                             NaN  
5556                           10.30  
6275                           14.10  
6409                           12.70  
6665                            8.30  
7621                            8.40  
7668                           12.10  
7792                            4.40  
7819                           10.20  
8664                           12.90  
8701                            4.40  
9575                            9.30  
10066                           7.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to filter the dataframe based on 2 columns, the syntax for his would be

```py
df[(df[COLUMN_1_NAME]==PROPERTY_1_NAME) & (df[COLUMN_2_NAME]==PROPERTY_2_NAME)]
```

so in your case you would do (searching for 'GALLERY 37' and '2016')

```py
property_name = "GALLERY 37"
data_year = "2016"
ghg_intensity_df = df[(df['Property Name']==property_name) & (df['Data Year']==data_year)]
ghg_intensity = ghg_intensity_df['GHG Intensity (kg CO2e/sq ft)'].iloc[0]
print(ghg_intensity)
```

> This assumes that for every **Property Name** and **Data Year** pairs there would exist one and only one value

Comment: but how do I achieve this in function form using `def` ? Thanks for your help!